# Sympy integration involving inverse trig is incorrect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I'm not sure why, but the Sympy is not outputting the correct antiderivative for ∫(1/(a^2 + x^2))dx, with `a` being a constant value. The solution should be (arctan(x/a))/a, but Sympy says otherwise. From my Jupyter session:
[image]

I also tried telling letting Sympy know that `a` was a member of the reals, but it didn't particularly help:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I might be using the library incorrectly?

Comment: A response like that in Out[42] is sympy's way of saying 'I can't do that.'

Comment: Also filed this as a bug on Github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12050#issuecomment-273188218

Looks like the second result is a bug, and the first is a correct equivalent expression to the arctan solution.  Also, the issue can be fixed by specifying a as positive.